# Eager Loading in EF 5 fails with deep graph (using .include())

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, eager-loading

I am using code first with EF 5. Here is my test domain

```
    public class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Query Query { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public Query()
    {
        ChildrenA = new HashSet<ChildA>();
        ChildrenB = new HashSet<ChildB>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Master Master { get; set; }
    public ChildB SpecialChild { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildA> ChildrenA { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildB> ChildrenB { get; private set; }

    public ChildB GetChildByName(string name)
    {
        return ChildrenB.Where(c => c.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public class ChildA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Query_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Query Query { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Query SpecialQuery { get; set; }
    public int Query_Id { get; set; }
    public Query Query { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my context:

```
    public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        :base()
    {
    }
    public TestContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
            .Property(m => m.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
            .HasKey(m => m.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Query>()
            .Property(q => q.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Query>()
            .HasKey(q => q.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Query>()
            .HasOptional(q => q.Master)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(m => m.Query);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Query>()
            .HasOptional(q => q.SpecialChild)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(c => c.SpecialQuery);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildA>()
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildA>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.Query_Id, c.Id });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildA>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Query)
            .WithMany(q => q.ChildrenA)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.Query_Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildB>()
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildB>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.Query_Id, c.Id});
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildB>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Query)
            .WithMany(m => m.ChildrenB)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.Query_Id);
    }

    public DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChildA> ChildrenA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChildB> ChildrenB { get; set; }
}
```

Note: the compound PKs are to allow EF to force entity deletion when an object is removed from the collection in the POCO classes.

Here is some code to load test data:

```
            System.Data.Entity.Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
        string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};", SQLCEFileName());
        using (TestContext context = new TestContext(connectionString))
        {
            Master master = new Master() { Name = "Master1", Query = new Query() { Name = "Query1" } };
            master.Query.ChildrenA.Add(new ChildA() { Name = "ChildA1" });
            master.Query.ChildrenB.Add(new ChildB() { Name = "ChildB1" });
            master.Query.ChildrenB.Add(new ChildB() { Name = "ChildB2" });
            master.Query.ChildrenB.Add(new ChildB() { Name = "ChildB3" });
            master.Query.ChildrenB.Add(new ChildB() { Name = "ChildB4" });
            context.Masters.Add(master);
            Query special = new Query() { Name = "Special" };
            ChildB c3 = master.Query.GetChildByName("ChildB3");
            c3.SpecialQuery = special;
            special.ChildrenA.Add(new ChildA() { Name = "SpecialChildA1" });
            special.ChildrenB.Add(new ChildB() { Name = "SpecialChildB1" });
            special.ChildrenB.Add(new ChildB() { Name = "SpecialChildB2" });
            special.ChildrenB.Add(new ChildB() { Name = "SpecialChildB3" });
            special.ChildrenB.Add(new ChildB() { Name = "SpecialChildB4" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Now, as you will see there is an optional relationship back from ChildB to Query. So a ChildB can have a Query which can then have it's own list of ChildA and ChildB. In practice that is as deep as it goes.

When I query a Master and force Eager Loading by using include() on the lowest level of a Query (Master.Query.ChildrenB.SpecialQuery.Children[A or B]) then only one collection (ChildrenA or ChildrenB) gets loaded.

Here is an example query which should force the entire graph to load:

```
            using (TestContext context = new TestContext(connectionString))
        {
            Master master = context.Masters
                        .Where(m => m.Name == "Master1")
                        .Include("Query.ChildrenA")
                        .Include("Query.ChildrenB.SpecialQuery.ChildrenA")
                        .Include("Query.ChildrenB.SpecialQuery.ChildrenB")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
            ChildB c = master.Query.GetChildByName("Child3");
        }
```

Note: I know the syntax referencing entities in my collections below is wrong, I am just using it to illustrate the problem.

At this point master.Query.ChildrenB[2].SpecialQuery.ChildrenA.Count is 1 (Correct)
master.Query.ChildrenB[2].SpecialQuery.ChildrenB.Count is 0 (Should be 4)

If I modify the query and remove .Include("Query.ChildrenB.SpecialQuery.ChildrenA") then master.Query.ChildrenB[2].SpecialQuery.ChildrenB.Count is 4 as expected.

This is really weird since the collections in master.Query.ChildrenA and master.Query.ChildrenB load just fine.

Am I missing something here?

Many thanks to all assisters.

Answer (score 1):

I have no explanation, but just tested with EF 5.0 on .NET 4.0 in VS 2010 using **SQL Server 2008 R2 Express**. I've copied and pasted your code except that I removed the explicit connection string because apparently you are using SQL Server CE 4.0.

For me it works as you expect which raises the question if the SQL Server CE provider has a bug here.

The only difference I had is that the ChildB in question (`"ChildB3"`, I think) has index 3 in my collection, not index 2 like in your test. I also tested after removing all `virtual` keywords to disable lazy loading but I had the same (successful) result.

Screenshot from my test:

[image: Lots of Includes]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am using VS2012, .Net 4.5 and EF5. I have just switched it to use SQL Express 2012 and get the same result. I will post in a "Answer"

Comment: Can't post a screenshot unfortunately due to some weird score not being achieved however the result remains the same, an empty ChildrenB collection. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, the plot thickens. Have just setup a VM on Win7 x64, VS2010, SQL Express 2008 R2, .Net4 and all works correctly as per Slauma's response. Will now move working project to alternative environments to see what happens.

Comment: Moved working project back to dev environment (Windows8 x64, VS2010, SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2012 Express) and problem returns. Will post to Microsoft for investigation.